# Android Studio's Hypervisor keeps having the same error, have tried everything that i could find online

Tags: android, android-studio, hypervisor

When i try to download the Hypervisor driver for android studio, i keep getting the same error.
HAVE turned on SVM.
HAVE turned off Hyper-V.

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)".

Preparing "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)".
```

Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v1.RemotePackage@8ea227fd" (extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver) should be installed in
"C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver" but
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gvm-windows_v1_6_0.zip
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) in C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2\package.xml
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' in 'C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2'
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

[Video to show](https://vimeo.com/474167622)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Even new reinstall has same problem, so its likely either a bug or something wrong with Windows 10.

Tested using renamed sdk directory, reinstall minimal sdk in new directory after launching Android Studio, problem persists.

Part of the error message says file a bug with the Android Studio team. I have not done it yet.